# Splitting a column into 2 in a csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file with 100 rows of data displayed like this

"Jim    1234"

"Sam    1235"

"Mary   1236"

"John   1237"

What I'm trying to achieve is splitting the numbers from the names into 2 columns in python

edit*

Using,

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s+')
    df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

I managed to get it to display like this in excel[image]

However, the numbers still do not show up in column B as I expected.

Comment: See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html - the delimiter is " ". If you have problems, try to write some code and post the code here for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data have only one column and a tab delimiter:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', quoting=1, header=None, squeeze=True) \
  .str.split('\t', expand=True) \
  .to_csv('result.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: @LingYanMeng. If you edit the OP post, you will see this is a tabulation and not spaces. HTML code remove multiple spaces and replace tabulation by only one space.

Comment: None of your answers work even if you change `'\s+'` by `'\t'`  or `'"(.*) (.*)"'` by `'"(.*)\t(.*)"'`...

Answer (score 0):

if your file resemble to the picture below then the next code will work [csv file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3WkI.png)

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', header=None, delimiter='\s')
df
```

[code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s57MK.png)

Answer (score 0):

very simple way,

```
data=pd.DataFrame(['Jim1234','Sam4546'])
data[0].str.split('(\d+)', expand=True)
```